# How to Use Dart Route API

Tags: dart, html5-history

I have created a sample app to test the [Dart Route API](https://github.com/dart-lang/route).  I have the following code:

**`urls.dart`**

```dart
library urls;

import 'package:route/url_pattern.dart';

final homeUrl = new UrlPattern(r'/');
final otherScreenUrl = new UrlPattern(r'/other_screen/');
```

**`main.html`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <p id="sample_text_id"></p>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**`main.dart`**

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:route/client.dart';

import 'urls.dart';

void main() {
  var router = new Router()
    ..addHandler(homeUrl, _showHome)
    ..addHandler(otherScreenUrl, _showOtherScreen)
    ..listen();

  querySelector("#sample_text_id")
    ..text = "Click me!"
    ..onClick.listen(_gotoOtherScreen);
}

_gotoOtherScreen(MouseEvent event) {
  // I am trying to navigate to the "other screen" by using history.pushState here
  window.history.pushState({'url' : otherScreenUrl}, "other screen", otherScreenUrl);
}

_showHome(String path) {
  querySelector("#other_element")
    ..remove();
}

_showOtherScreen(String path) {
  querySelector("#sample_container_id")
    ..append(new SpanElement()
      ..innerHtml = "now in other screen"
      ..id = "other_element");
}
```

I am getting the following errors when running the app and then clicking on the `<p>` tag:

> Breaking on exception: Illegal argument(s): No handler found for
>   /test/web/main.html
>
> Exception: Illegal argument(s): No handler found for
>   /test/web/main.html   Router._getUrl (package:route/client.dart:53:7) 
>   Router.handle (package:route/client.dart:71:22)
>   Router.listen. (package:route/client.dart:102:15)
>
> Breaking on exception: type 'UrlPattern' is not a subtype of type
>   'String' of 'url'.
>
> Exception: type 'UrlPattern' is not a subtype of type 'String' of
>   'url'.   _gotoOtherScreen
>   `(http://127.0.0.1:3030/test/web/main.dart:18:27)`

**How is the Route API supposed to be used?  What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the updated code that solves the above issues:

**`urls.dart`**

```dart
library urls;

import 'package:route/url_pattern.dart';

final homeUrl = new UrlPattern(r'(.*)/');
final homeUrlWithFile = new UrlPattern(r'(.*)/main.html');
final otherScreenUrl = new UrlPattern(r'(.*)/other_screen');
```

**`main.html`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <a href="/other_screen">click me!!</a>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**`main.dart`**

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:route/client.dart';

import 'urls.dart';


void main() {
  var router = new Router()
    ..addHandler(homeUrl, _showHome)
    ..addHandler(homeUrlWithFile, _showHome)
    ..addHandler(otherScreenUrl, _showOtherScreen)
    ..listen();
}

_showHome(String path) {
  var e = querySelector("#other_element");
  if (e != null) e.remove();
}

_showOtherScreen(String path) {
  querySelector("#sample_container_id")
    ..append(new SpanElement()
      ..innerHtml = "now in other screen"
      ..id = "other_element");
}
```